# unix socket creation then fork(), messaging gets mixed up

Tags: c, linux, fork, haproxy, unix-socket

I'm currently trying to solve an issue where I create a `process A`, which creates a Unix socket to connect to a server process. I then fork the `process A` and get a new child `process B`. At this point I have 2 processes, with duplicate descriptors,etc..  when `process B` sends a message to the server, the server processes the message and then sends it back to `process A` (but it should go back to `process B`).  I am certain this is because `A` and `B` are duplicates, and somehow the Unix socket from the server's perspective is still a `" process A socket"`, and all messages will go back to A no matter who sends them.

Is there any way to resolve this other than disconnecting and reconnecting post-fork in both processes A and B? (The process `A` and `B` are haproxy in master/worker mode)? Thanks!

Comment: Is this for communication between A and B ?

Comment: sorry, no i want A to talk to the server and get its responses back, and B to talk to the server and its responses back..

Comment: I would expect process B to also be able to receive the replies from the server in principle, but if B is sending the request it's possible that A is more likely to win the inherent race here. Does B receive replies that the server sends for A's requests?

Comment: No i think no matter who sends them, the responses go back to A.. i am thinking because process A did the connect() (before the fork), the os somehow directs the messages from the server to that process. i have a feeling each process needs to disconnect and make a new socket completely, but i was hoping there would be another way, but i am not optimistic :)

Comment: The response will go back to whichever process happens to read it first. If both processes are blocked in `read()` at the same time, it's unpredictable which one will get the response.

Comment: Ahh, okay, and I assume the only way to separate them would be to deinitialize and reinitialize to make a new socket.. i bet i have to do that with both processes because deinitalizing either one will close the server side..    i think you have confirmed what I kind of expected..

Comment: This is linux but I think at least in windows the processes cannot listen to the same port.
https://serverfault.com/questions/426744/can-multiple-servers-listen-on-the-same-port-when-no-bind-accept-has-occured

Comment: Your suspicion is wrong. You don't need to reopen the socket in both the parent and the child. After the `fork()`, the file descriptors in the processes refer to the same file description, which is why either of the processes can read the reply. If one of the processes closes its file descriptor, the file description is unaffected, because the other process still holds a reference to it. You only have to close and reopen the connection in *one* of the processes.

Comment: That would be good, i will play around  with this.. Thanks!

Comment: And this socket, is it TCP or UDP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some additional research and there is another way to do this, I learned about pthread_atfork() which sets up functions to be called by the parent and the child upon fork..  i actually used this mechanism to stop and start the network functionality on the child, and it worked!

https://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_atfork

Answer (score 3):

> I'm currently trying to solve an issue where I create a process A,
> which creates a Unix socket to connect to a server process. I then
> fork the process A and get a new child process B. At this point I have
> 2 processes, with duplicate descriptors,etc..

You pass over those details quickly, but I don't think you fully appreciate the significance.  Process B does inherit copies of all A's open file descriptors across the `fork()`, but that doesn't mean the socket itself is copied.  How would that work?  As far as the remote peer is concerned, there's only one connection.  What B has inherited is a process-specific association between an integer file descriptor number and a (non-process-specific) table of open file descriptions maintained by the operating system.  Thus, B doesn't have a copy of the original socket, but rather *the same socket*.

> when process B sends a
> message to the server, the server processes the message and then sends
> it back to process A (but it should go back to process B).

The remote server doesn't know A from B.  It has only the one connection, and that's where it directs its response.  In principle, either A or B could receive it, but it is plausible that A consistently wins that race.

> I am
> certain this is because A and B are duplicates,

Yes, partially.

> and somehow the Unix
> socket from the server's perspective is still a " process A socket",
> and all messages will go back to A no matter who sends them.

No.  See above.

> Is there any way to resolve this other than disconnecting and
> reconnecting post-fork in both processes A and B?

If it's a viable solution for B to reconnect, then what about having it establish its own connection in the first place, instead of inheriting one from A?  But if A needs to establish the connection on behalf of B, then A should close it after forking B to hand it over for B's exclusive use.  If A needs its own connection to the server then it can establish a new one after the fork.  Alternatively, having its own connection already open, A can establish a second connection before forking, and hand that one off to B, retaining its own original one.  In that case, not only would A want to close its copy of B's connection, but B would want to close its copy of A's.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response.. I will definitely take a look at the feasibility of just  not making the connection until after the fork, or reconnecting..  the only issue is that the application is haproxy and i was hoping to avoid changing it, but that's not a requirement, i will take a look!